# Is it possible to give the Facebook page plugin rounded corners?

Tags: html, css, facebook, plugins

I'm using the Page Plugin from Facebook which displays a Facebook page feed on a website. The plugin is only a small amount of HTML code that goes into whatever file your using to make your website.

This is the code:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/UrchinBooks-Shop/922785527788785?fref=ts" data-width="250" data-height="340" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/UrchinBooks-Shop/922785527788785?fref=ts"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/UrchinBooks-Shop/922785527788785?fref=ts">UrchinBooks Shop</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

I've tried using the classes of the div's in my stylesheet but that doesn't do anything. I also tried to add a style tag to all the div's as well. Nothing there either.

Is it possible to give the box that displays on the webpage, the one that's generated by the plugin, rounded corners?

Comment: i need more explanation

Comment: When you add the plugin to a web page, it has square corners. I'd like to give it rounded corners, preferably using css border-radius. I want to do this because there's I have a background to the plugin that has rounded corners, and the square one's on the plugin don't match. I'm wondering if it's possible to give the plugin round corners.

Comment: If the plugin has CSS you can overwrite the style, otherwise from your style stylesheet you can overwrite the class propeties

Comment: The plugin is basically a bunch of div's nested inside each other, that goes into a html file. There's also a blockquote and an anchor nested in there as well. None of the div's have the style attribute. There's no css file that comes with the plugin. Some of the div's have classes and I've tried using those in my stylesheet, but nothing is working. I might try to target those classes in my stylesheet to see if I can make any changes, just to see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to give the plugin rounded corners;

Go into the developer tools in your browser and go through the HTML until you find the place where the HTML code for the plugin is located. Expand all the div's, spans and anything else until you find the iFrame tag. You will need to use this iFrame tag in your stylesheet. For me it was:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe
```

but it may be different for other people as the plugin may work differently.

Basically, you use that iFrame in your stylesheet. For me, I used the developer tools to find the iFrame tag, then I found a CSS selector associated with that iFrame tag, and I used that CSS selector in my stylesheet.